# R: How to identify first date of positive observation by ID for multiple columns?

Tags: r

I would like to identify first date of positive observation by ID for multiple columns.

Example dataframe:

```
ID  date  Observ1 Observ2 Observ3
 1     1        1       0       0
 1     2        0       1       0
 1     3        1       0       1
 2     1        1       1       0
```

Desired result:

```
ID  FirstObserv1 FirstObserv2 FirstObserv3
 1             1            2            3
 2             1            1           NA
```

For single column of observation, I can solve it with dplyr:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter( Observ1 > 0) %>% summarize( FirstObserv1 = min(date) ) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Having no idea how to do it for multiple column at once, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reshaping your data like this using `tidyverse` functions. The key of the code id filtering those values with value of 1 and then set a filter to extract the min date value using `filter()`. After that you reshape to wide and you get the expected output. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
dfnew <- df %>% pivot_longer(-c(ID,date)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(value==1) %>% select(-value) %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(ID,name) %>%
  filter(date==min(date)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=date)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID Observ1 Observ2 Observ3
  <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1     1       1       2       3
2     2       1       1      NA
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), date = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L
), Observ1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Observ2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
    Observ3 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Good one Duck , same approach till filter(value == 1), but got stuck there. Steep learning curve.

Comment: @KarthikS For sure!!! All is about learning curve :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method which just replaces the observation with `date` if the observation is positive and `NA` otherwise. Getting the `min` of each observation yields the desired results.

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Observ")), ~ifelse(. > 0, date, NA)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("Observ")), min, na.rm = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>      ID Observ1 Observ2 Observ3
#>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     1       1       2       3
#> 2     2       1       1     Inf
```

Comment: I like this solution as it looks clean and avoids reshaping the data couple times. My only gripe with this is that `NAs` will  be treated as `Inf` by `min`, is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: The behaviour of `min` can't be changed. The only way is to add another step to replace `Inf` with `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(across(
    -date, 
    list(First = ~{x <- which(. > 0); if (length(x) > 0L) date[[x[[1L]]]] else NA_real_}), 
    .names = "{.fn}{.col}"
  ))
```

Output

```
     ID FirstObserv1 FirstObserv2 FirstObserv3
  <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1     1            1            2            3
2     2            1            1           NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) which(x > 0)[1]),
            ID, .SDcols = patterns('^Observ')]
#   ID Observ1 Observ2 Observ3
#1:  1       1       2       3
#2:  2       1       1      NA
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     summarise(across(starts_with('Obser'), ~ which(. > 0)[1], 
        .names = 'First{col}'), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#     ID FirstObserv1 FirstObserv2 FirstObserv3
#  <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>
#1     1            1            2            3
#2     2            1            1           NA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), date = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L
), Observ1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Observ2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
    Observ3 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: isn't the last argument .groups = 'drop' default? For ex: > df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(across(starts_with('Obser'), ~ which(. > 0)[1], .names = 'First{col}')) %>% group_vars()
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
character(0)
> df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(across(starts_with('Obser'), ~ which(. > 0)[1], .names = 'First{col}'), .groups = 'drop') %>% group_vars()
character(0)
>  both give same output. Could you please help in understading the significance of explicitly mentioning the .groups = 'drop' argument.

Comment: @KarthikS it is `'drop_last'`